# Cakephp add Html attributes

Tags: html, cakephp

I need Cakephp to create an input field using `$this->Form->input()` and in this field parameter add Html attribute - `required="required"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the documentation. The second argument takes all options (html and otherwise):

```
$this->Form->input('field_name', array('required'=>true));
```

Comment: Also don't forget that you can set `required` in your model's validation too!

Comment: Or even better: to the database's table field. if its "NOT NULL" it will automatically be a "required" field.